# Don't understand the algebra at the end of this inductive proof.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

So, can anyone explain the algebra at the end of this inductive proof?
[image]

I am confused in how they are getting line 1 to line 2 and then also how they get from line 2 to line 3.

Comment: It seems that the base of the logarithm is $2$. What are they proving?

Comment: Let me add the entire proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the base of the logarithm is $2$, since otherwise this proof is false. I'm going to do the steps with more intermediate detail:

$$2\left(2^k\log_2\left(2^k\right)\right)+2^{k+1}$$

$$2^{k+1}\log_2\left(2^k\right)+2^{k+1}$$

$$2^{k+1}\left(\log_2\left(2^k\right)+1\right)$$

$$2^{k+1}\left(\log_2\left(2^k\right)+\log_2(2)\right)$$

Using the fact that $\log_a(b)+\log_a(c) = \log_a(bc)$:

$$2^{k+1}\cdot\log_2\left(2^{k+1}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks!  I am not sure I ever would have thought of that on my own.  Oh well, I don't really have a lot of experience doing the algebraic manipulations that these proofs require.  The overall structure of these inductive proofs make a lot of sense to me but I just find the algebra required to be so hard! :(

Comment: @timbram The only good way to get better at this is practice. Look exactly at what you're trying to achieve. Try to factor things out. Try to use properties of the functions in question (e.g. the property of $\log$ that I used). Practice this and I have no doubt that you'll get better.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement!  Just out of curiosity, do a lot of people new to proofs have trouble with the algebra?

Comment: @timbram I'm not sure, but I can't imagine it's that uncommon. How removed are you from your most recent algebra class?

Comment: About 10 years actually.

Comment: @timbram Ok. I imagine it's just lack of practice with algebraic expressions. Just keep working on them and you'll get better in no time!

Comment: @timbram By the way, $\log_2\left(2^{k+1}\right)=k+1$.